# Unable to Copy unmatched Nodes while Grouping

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am unable to find out what I should be doing to get desired output as below.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <empID>12345</empID>
        <Location>NY</Location>
        <Remote/>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>23456</empID>
        <Local/>
        <Location>NY</Location>
        <City>NYC</City>
        <CityAllowance>100</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>23456</empID>
        <Local>Y</Local>
        <Location>NY</Location>
        <City>Syracuse</City>
        <CityAllowance>150</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>23456</empID>
        <Local>Y</Local>
        <Location>NY</Location>
        <City>Ithaca</City>
        <CityAllowance>250</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>88001</empID>
        <Local/>
        <Location>CA</Location>
        <City>San Franscisco</City>
        <CityAllowance>200</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>        
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>88001</empID>
        <Local>Y</Local>
        <Location>CA</Location>
        <City>San Jose</City>
        <CityAllowance>190</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <Amount>9450</Amount>        
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>88001</empID>
        <Local>Y</Local>
        <Location>CA</Location>
        <City>Oakland</City>
        <CityAllowance>600</CityAllowance>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <Amount>4500</Amount>        
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

My XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>            
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <Workers>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N']" group-by="empID">
                <Worker>                    
                    <empID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </empID>                    
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Workers>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <empID>12345</empID>
        <Location>NY</Location>
        <Remote/>
        <Amount>1450</Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>23456</empID>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>88001</empID>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Current Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Worker>
      <empID>23456</empID>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <empID>88001</empID>
   </Worker>
</Workers>
```

- I wanted to copy all nodes exactly as they appear in Source XML if
  value of `<Local>` is either `Y` or `N`. However, this is not getting copied down with my current XSLT
- For-each-group statement `<xsl:for-each-group select="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N']" group-by="empID">` was written to handle records that have `<Local>` value is either set to `Y` or `N`

My application supports both `XSLT 3.0` and `XSLT 2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a key and add empty templates for the elements you don't want to output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                expand-text="yes">
  
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
    <xsl:key name="group" match="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N']" use="empID"/>

    <xsl:template match="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N'][not(. is key('group', empID)[1])]"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N'][. is key('group', empID)[1]]/*[not(self::empID)]"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to group some elements but process all with `for-each-group` one way would be to use a variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                expand-text="yes">
  
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="groups" as="element(Worker)*">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker" composite="yes" group-by="Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N', empID">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]">
                <xsl:sequence select="."/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups/."/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N']/*[not(self::empID)]"/>
  
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Perhaps it is better to move the grouping code to a function, so that the template body for `Workers` remains compact:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
                expand-text="yes">
  
    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(Worker)*">
      <xsl:param name="workers" as="element(Worker)*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$workers" composite="yes" group-by="Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N', empID">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>
  
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:group(Worker)/."/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Worker[Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N']/*[not(self::empID)]"/>
  
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. this works. Could you please let me know what i should have added on my XSLT to get the desired output? or Is that not a right approach at all to get what i wanted? Any hints to fix my xslt is greatly appreciated

Comment: @KM6895, well, if your template matching `Workers` only processes certain `Worker` children but the others not at all it is obvious why elements are missing. If the order doesn't matter simply precede your for-each-group with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="Worker[not(Remote = 'Y' or Remote = 'N')]"/>`, if the order does matter see the edit.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm testing using the Solutions you provided

Comment: @KM6895#, is the question answered so that you can mark it as resolved by accepting the answer?

Comment: Thank you Martin. I have just accepted the answer. I have been testing it and seeing some issues but issues are not due to the solution you provided. That has more to do with additional requirement changes. Apologies for the delay in accepting the answer.